# How to request that a close vote be reviewed?

Tags: discussion, reopen-closed

One of my SO questions was marked as duplicate.  I revised the question and added a comment to indicate why I felt it was not a duplicate.  How can you request that the close vote be reviewed/removed?

Comment: You have done all that you can.

Comment: You can hop into the [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers)  room and ask the regulars if they see remaining issues or have advice how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you edit your question to clarify why it isn't a duplicate or why the question isn't "unclear/too broad/etc", you are already getting a "review".  A single close vote is nothing more than a single close vote (with the exception of a Gold Badge holders special dup closing privileges).  It still takes 4 more people who agree with the close vote to close the question.

Other users who encounter your question should see your edits and your explanation, and make their own judgement as to whether the question needs to be closed.

However, until the existing close votes are retracted or expire, nothing can be done.  To remove a specific vote, the specific individual who cast that vote needs removes it him/herself.  But unfortunately you don't know who cast all of the close votes until the question is closed (the only exception is with duplicates, since the first person to flag or vote to close will generate an auto-comment).

Now with Duplicate votes only, the moment the first vote is cast, a standard "Your question may already have an answer here" banner will appear above your question.  This banner is intended to be a signpost for **you** to direct you to the potential duplicate.  At this point, the banner is only visible to you.  No one else can see it.  It will not be visible to everyone until the question is closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks.   Right my concern was really about that banner - didn't want to scare away other reviewers. But as you pointed out (and @psubsee2003) that is only shown to the poster.

Comment: Ah, that is a good point about the banner. I always forget that it is shown to the asker after only a single vote. Been too long since I've asked a question, I suppose. :-)

Answer (score 9):

Comments aren't deleted because you think they're wrong.  You're free to reply to the comment indicating why you feel it is not correct, as you have, but the comment doesn't merit deletion by a moderator just because you don't like it.

Comment: It's not the comment I have an issue with.  It's that when people visit the question they see "Possible duplicate...." when I don't think that is accurate.  And this statement could dissuade someone from answering the question.

Comment: @MarcusLeon Again, you don't get to just delete it because you don't like it.  They have every right to see that someone else thinks that the question is a duplicate.  If they agree that it's a duplicate and choose not to answer, that's their decision, and they have every right to make it.

Comment: I just want someone to look at the follow up response to the dup vote and review whether they still feel it's a duplicate.  No issue with people contributing.  Goal is to keep the conversation going on whether it's a dup or not.  What is the harm in that?

Comment: @MarcusLeon So you want the conversation over whether or not its a duplicate to continue by deleting the comment/vote and preventing anyone from ever even knowing that someone thought it was a duplicate?  How does that enhance the conversation?  Sounds like you just want to prevent that conversation from existing.  The way to let the conversation continue is to provide your views in your own comment, and let readers read both sides and make their own decision.

Comment: I don't want to delete anything.  My goal is to have a dialogue with the person who (kindly) reviewed the question to highlight that this is unique case and if he/she agrees remove the close vote in order to encourage others to help answer the question.  But to previous point the comment does say _Possible_ duplicate.  Anyway we can let this go.  Obviously this is not a popular suggestion :)

Comment: @MarcusLeon You *are* asking for it to be deleted.  You were very explicit about asking exactly that.  If you want to have a dialog, then reply, and have a dialog.  Don't try to delete the comment and prevent a dialog from happening.  The only one trying to prevent a dialog is *you*.

Comment: I previously updated the question to not say deleted but to say reviewed...  bad choice of words.

Comment: @MarcusLeon but it will be reviewed by everyone else who sees the question.  It is just a close vote until you get more 4 people with 3K rep to agree.  And you may not be aware of this, but the banner above your question is not visible to anyone but you.  For everyone else, the only thing we see is the comment (and possibly the `(1)` next to close if they have enough rep to see it)

Comment: @MarcusLeon Your question still says you want the comment/vote removed.  If you want it to be reviewed, then the way to do that is to do nothing, and let people see it, at which point they can either also vote to close, or choose not to, after *having reviewed it*.

Comment: @psubsee2003 thank you.  Ultimately that is my objective!  Didn't realize that.  Thank you for taking the time to understand what I was trying to say and address the question.